# Как использовать значение ячейки для <img src в скрипте?

Tags: google-apps-script

Добавляю иконку в скрипт для отправки  почты.

Это работает:

```
body += '<img src=http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/12/517/w24h241386955471success8.png width="20" height="20">';
```

Понимаю, что должно выглядеть примерно так, но не получается.

```
body += '<img src= sheet.getRange("K1").getValue()  width="20" height="20">';
```

Вопрос, как подставить значение из ячейки `K1` (`url` иконки) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body += '<img src= ' + sheet.getRange("K1").getValue() + '  width="20" height="20">';
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь!